# Parse HTML styles in Regexp

Tags: html, regex, stylesheet

Don't know how to create a Regexp request to check smth like that:

```
p {
  margin:0
}
.c0 {
  width:468.0pt;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  padding:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt
}
.c1 {
  direction:ltr
}
```

It's a part of style in HTML document.So, p - tag, in every style of this tag (c0, c1, etc) there could be different count of properties, Every property has format of PROPERTY_NAME:PROPERTY_VALUE and this properties separated with ;

How to consider all of this things in one Regexp?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: does it have to take into account new lines?

Comment: No, there is just one text line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\.?\w+\s*{\s*(?:(?:(?<name>[^{};]+)\s*:\s*(?<value>[^{};]+));?)+\s*}
```

Output:
[image]

Analyzer:
[image]

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot! But I just can't understand it :). If you could add a little of explanation - you'll be the best! :)

Comment: Well, I advise you to use a Regex editor. For example, I use Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), which has a built-in Regex analyzer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again! That's really what I need to get into Regexp!